# Robot framework main.py failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets'

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, robotframework

I'm implementing a python code where i have to send and receive data from websocket client using WebSocket package.
My code is  fine if i run it using python, now i want to write Robot file to test it below the code and the robot content

```
  @keyword("START SERVER")
def start_websocket_server():
    websocket_server = websockets.serve(websocket_request_handler, "localhost", 7682)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocket_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Robot code

```
*** Settings ***
Library  ./main.py
*** Test Cases ***
START SERVER
```

When i run it got :

```
main.py' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ain.py", line 7, in <module>
    import websockets
```

It look like Robot cannot detect external python modules, Any idea how can solve this issue ?
How can i force Robot to load the system python env ?

Comment: Issue should not be related to robot but to the python interpreter and how you installed the websockets module. First time: never install anything into global space, always use virtual environment..

Comment: I'm using pycharm and i installed the version proposed by puycharm which is python 3.8